# How can I make a class use a function that takes properties from another class?

Tags: python, function, object, inheritance, abstract-base-class

I'm trying to make a class use a function from another class that uses properties from said other class.

Here's the problem in detail:

Let's say that we have a base class called `Worker`. Each `Worker` wants to work on a `House`. Each `Worker` has a list of `Task`s it can choose from and complete. Each `Task` has a `name`, a `description`, an `energy_cost` it takes to complete the task, and it also has a `do_task` function that allows the `Worker` to actually do the task.

Here's how we would represent this in code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class House(object): #The object a worker works on
    pass 

#Tasks start here   

class Task(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def name(self):
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def description(self):
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def energy_cost(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def do_task(self):
        pass


class Paint(Task):
    name = "Paint"
    description = "Paint a house partially"
    energy_cost = 20

    def do_task(self, house):
        #paint house here


class Slosh(Task):
    name = "Slosh"
    description = "Completely cover a house in paint"
    energy_cost = 40

    def do_task(self, house):
        #slosh house here

#Worker classes

class Worker(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.energy = 100
        self.current_task = None

    def set_task(self, task):
        self.current_task = task

    def work(self, house):
        self.energy -= self.current_task.energy_cost
        self.current_task.do_task(house)


class Painter(Worker):

    def __init__(self):
        self.task_list = [Paint, Slosh]
        super().__init__()
```

But what if we needed to access one of a `Worker`'s attributes in order to do a `Task`? Let's say a `Worker` had an attribute called `work_speed` that specified the speed at which the task is completed. How would a `Task` know what the `Worker`'s `work_speed` is? We could pass a `Worker` instance to a `Task` instance inside of a `Worker`'s task_list like this:

```
self.task_list = [Paint(self), Slosh(self)]
```

But that's clunky and also seems extremely unnecessary.

We could also inherit each `Task` in the class definition of a `Worker`, but we don't need the extra attributes, and the `do_task` method would be overridden if we had multiple `Task`s.

Ideally, a `Worker` should have the ability to do a `Task` in the form `worker.do_task()` so that `do_task` can access a `Worker`'s attributes, and it should be able to use properties like `energy_cost` defined inside of a `Task` object.

How would we go about doing that?

Comment: can you give an example of the intended functionality?

Comment: @Primusa Let's say a `Worker` uses `Paint` on a `House`. The `Worker` loses the energy specified in the `energy_cost`. The `House` gets painted. Later on, I want to be able to use the `name` and the `description` so that a user can see what each task is and does and then use that task.

Answer (score 0):

Why not separate your concerns; anything realted to the worker you perform in the worker's work function?

This tends to be my approach, if you need access to that worker's speed, current energy, whatever, do it in that worker's work function.

In the example that you posit, I would make a generic Worker superclass that different types of Workers would inheirit from, if I was going that route.

Then in the Worker superclass I'd do something like this:

```
class Worker():
"""The worker superclass, all workers inheirit from this"""
def work(self):
    """Perform the required task if any, deduct costs, if any, as necessary"""

    if self.current_task is not  None:
        if all(self.energy, self.current_task.energy_cost): self.energy -= self.current_task.energy_cost
        if all(self.money, self.current_task.monetary_cost): self.money -= self.current_task.monetary_cost
        if all(self.workspeed, self.current_task.duration): time.sleep(self.current_task.duration/self.workspeed)
        if self.current_task.do_task: self.current_task.do_task()
```

Then you can feel free to add properties as you like to the subclasses provided you have a case for it in the superclass. Otherwise youo can write a method for each subclass and call `super().work()` before/after each special case but that data mangling is really up to you.